# Filtrar elementos de acordo com tecla digitada Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um input que o usuário digita o filtro que deseja, a cada tecla pressionada quero efetuar um filtro, se o texto digitado conter no array quero que a #div_1 seja exibida caso contrario quero que a #div_2 seja exibida, podem me ajudar?

```
$('#term').keyup(function(){    
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); 
        var elementos = ['japonesa', 'paris 6', 'jundiai'];

        if(elementos.indexOf(val) != -1)    {
            $('#div_1').show();
        }else{
            $('#div_2').show();
        }     

    });
```

Comment: E qual é o problema? Não funcionou? Deu algum erro? Qual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente sua intenção, acho que só está faltando alternar entre `show` e `hide`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="term"></input>
        <div id="div_1"><h1>Div #1</h1></div>
        <div id="div_2"><h1>Div #2</h1></div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
        $('#div_1').hide();
        $('#div_2').hide();

        $('#term').keyup(function() {
            var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            var elementos = ['japonesa', 'paris 6', 'jundiai'];

            if (elementos.indexOf(val) != -1) {
                $('#div_1').show();
                $('#div_2').hide();
            } else {
                $('#div_1').hide();
                $('#div_2').show();
            }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```